# How do you call a variable that was returned at the end of a function?

Tags: python, function, return

I created this function and want to call the returned result but, I'm not sure how to get the variable back. If possible I'd also like a different message to pop up if the user types n. Could anyone help?

```
def give_entertainment():
 random_form_of_entertainment = random.choice(form_of_entertainment)
 good_user_input = "y"
 while good_user_input == "y":
      user_input = input(f"We have chosen {random_form_of_entertainment} for your entertainment! Sound good? y/n: ")
      if good_user_input != user_input:
           random_form_of_entertainment = random.choice(form_of_entertainment)
           continue
      else:
           print("Awesome! Glad we got that figured out. Your trip is all planned! ")
           return random_form_of_entertainment
```

Comment: `result = give_entertainment()`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = give_entertainment()
```

Should store the return of your function into `x`.

With:

```
print(x)
```

you should see what's stored in your `x` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method while assigning it to a variable.

```py
some_var = your_method()
```

Now this `some_var` variable have the returning value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use a recursive function for this, I made it work with y/n/invalid_input cases. Also with this an invalid input won't update random_form_of_entertainment so the user has to say y or n for it to change. I hope this is what you're looking for!

```
def give_entertainment():
    random_form_of_entertainment = random.choice(forms_of_entertainment)
    good_user_input = "y"
    bad_user_input = "n"
    invalid_input = True
    while invalid_input:
        user_input = input(f'We have chosen {random_form_of_entertainment} for your entertainment! Sound good? y/n: ')
        if user_input == good_user_input:
            print("Awesome! Glad we got that figured out. Your trip is all planned for!")
            return random_form_of_entertainment
        elif user_input == bad_user_input:
            print("Sorry to hear that, let me try again...")
            return give_entertainment()
        else:
            print("I don't recognize that input, please try again.")
            continue

chosen_result = give_entertainment()
print(f'You chose {chosen_result}!')
```